# Why the group of input text and radio buttons aren't displaying with proper order & padding

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I add some form input with radio buttons in bootstrap.
i wanted them to diplay in the following ways:

- case-1: if the screen is large enough, then display both input text & radio buttons inline in same order.
- case-2: if the screen is small  enough, then display input text in one line & radio buttons on next line with proper padding to maintain alignment with other elements.

But instead of that, this is happening:

- case-1: if the screen is large enough, it displays input text & radio buttons in **opposite order**! Please check image given below:

[image]

- case-2: if the screen is small  enough, it display input text **without proper padding**. Please check image given below:

[image]

please suggest me on fixing this problem.

Here is the source code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container" >
         <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-primary"  >
               <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h3 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;">
                     Information    
                  </h3>
               </div>
               <div class="panel-body">
                  <form class="form-horizontal" >
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-3"  for="employeeid">ID:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                           <div class="input-group">    
                              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"  aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="employeeid"  placeholder="Enter ID">      
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group form-inline">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-3" style="text-align:right;" >Type:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="insurance"  placeholder="Select Type">  
                        <div class="col-sm-3"> 
                           <label class="radio-inline">
                           <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio0" value="0"  onchange="" checked>Single
                           </label>
                           <label class="radio-inline">
                           <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio1" value="200"  onchange="">Wife
                           </label>
                           <label class="radio-inline">
                           <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio2" value="300"  onchange="">Children
                           </label>          
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </form>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

please let me know if any further information is required.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Put your `textbox with id="insurance"` inside `div with class 'col-sm-3'` and put your `radio buttons` inside `div with class col-sm-6`. This will properly structure your controls and is in adherence to the 'BootStrap Grid system'. You can read more about the Bootstrap Grid Template [here](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)

```
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="insurance"  placeholder="Select Type">  </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">  
                       <label class="radio-inline">

                       <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio0" value="0"  onchange="" checked>Single
                       </label>
                       <label class="radio-inline">
                       <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio1" value="200"  onchange="">Wife
                       </label>
                       <label class="radio-inline">
                       <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio2" value="300"  onchange="">Children
                       </label>                                     
                    </div>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container" >
         <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-primary"  >
               <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h3 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;">
                     Information    
                  </h3>
               </div>
               <div class="panel-body">
                  <form class="form-horizontal" >
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-3"  for="employeeid">ID:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                           <div class="input-group">    
                              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"  aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="employeeid"  placeholder="Enter ID">      
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group form-inline">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-3" style="text-align:right;" >Type:</label>
                       <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="insurance"  placeholder="Select Type">  </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6"> 
                           <label class="radio-inline">
                             
                           <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio0" value="0"  onchange="" checked>Single
                           </label>
                           <label class="radio-inline">
                           <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio1" value="200"  onchange="">Wife
                           </label>
                           <label class="radio-inline">
                           <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio2" value="300"  onchange="">Children
                           </label>          
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </form>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it works. also if understand your suggestion then, you are saying that: there could problem, if less or more than 12 columns in one line.Thanks @Alorika.

Comment: Yes, we should maintain the grid system, so that the structure will remain intact and will not get disturbed while resizing.

Answer (score 1):

add margin to your "Select Type" textbox

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="insurance"  placeholder="Select Type" style = "margin: auto 5px;>
```

EDIT:

also padding and margin functions differently. whereas, padding is the gap inside the element and margin is the gap outside the element. see the illustration below took from google chrome's developer tool

[image]